# how i convert and use Xml file in our application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new in iPhone Application Programming. 
I can't get value from XML file and display it in UITableView. I need to get the name value of animal. How is the simple way to parse XML without attribute? I've been read NSXMLParser Documentation but the data is not displayed in my UITableView.

Here is my XML file :

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
       <Emp_Code>1</Emp_Code>
       <Emp_Name>Arun</Emp_Name>
       <Emp_Salary>17750</Emp_Salary>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
       <Emp_Code>2</Emp_Code>
       <Emp_Name>Raja</Emp_Name>
       <Emp_Salary>18050</Emp_Salary>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

how i convert and use in my project please suggest me.

Comment: So we need the parsing code and your table code :)

Comment: i give the parsing code in question

and i think i save values in array then print in uitableview.
is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use TBXML all the time I need to parse an XML. It's really easy if you know the structure of the XML file to parse. ;-)
See here: http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html

Comment: I use it too and it is very fast and fairly easy to use.